# MISRA C violation Directive 4.14

Tags: c, misra

> The validity of values received from external sources shall be checked

```
    int fun (uint8 * Data)
    {
        if (Data != NULL) {
            *Data = 0x00u;
            return(E_OK);    
        }
   }
```

Does any body have any idea how to fix above warning? Even though I am checking the NULL pointer still I am getting the violation of Misra 4.14 I,e...validity of values from external sources shall be checked.

How to fix above warning?

Comment: Which tool do you use for checking the rules?

Comment: Should you be returning something if `Data == NULL` ?

Comment: As an aside it looks like there's a missing control path for return value.

Comment: Which version of the misra guidelines do you refer to?

Comment: Is it possible that it is the *call* to that function that your checker flags, as opposed to the function implementation?

Comment: Aside: in the function not all control paths return a value.

Comment: @Hulk I think the question is about rule 14.4, but the OP looked up directive 4.14 instead.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed, this seems likely, but I don't think we can really answer the OP's question without further information. One is completely unrelated, the other not violated here, and the code shown is reaching the end of a non-void function.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's fine unless the caller intends to read that return value

Comment: @ArdentCoder for some values of "fine". It is certainly not MISRA compliant.

Comment: @Hulk That's what I said, *unless the caller intends to read that return value*. And I don't know what misra is, my comment was not about that.

Comment: The error message is consistent with Directive 4.14

Comment: @Andrew yes, the error message matches Directive 4.14, but the code does not contain anything that might be considered a violation of that. That's why I suspect that the OP misread the output of the tool that produced the warning, and it either refers to a different source location, or a different rule (or a false positive). Only OP can clarify this.

Comment: the posted code says:  if the data is not NULL, then set it to NULL.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: @user3629249 it says: if the given *pointer* is not NULL, dereference it and set the pointed-to `uint8`-value to zero, which may be reasonable.

Comment: @ArdentCode - MISRA is the Motor Industry Software Reliability Association. Its aims are to encourage code safety, security, portability, and reliability in embedded systems written in C and C++.

Comment: @ArdentCode - Although its definition comes from motor industry, it is nowadays used at least as a starting point for safety-relevant C and C++ code in many other industries, including railway, automation etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not violate MISRA-C:2012 ***rule 14.4*** (note the spelling).

A violation of that rule would be to write `if(Data)` instead of `if(Data != NULL)`. The former violates 14.4, the latter is MISRA-C compliant.

Edit:

There is however a ***directive 4.14*** (note the spelling) *The validity of values received from external sources shall be checked*, which was added to MISRA-C:2012 with the first amendment AMD-1. That directive is regarding sanitizing input from external sources such as files, user input, communication channels etc. It has absolutely nothing to do with your question.

Comment: but MISRA-C:2012 14.4 does not mention "The validity of values received from external sources shall be checked", therefore I suspect another version is in use. 2004 14.4 does not fit either, so I guess the OP will have to clarify.

Comment: @Hulk Aah wait, it's not a rule, it's a directive. Will update the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is probably what the OP is quoting. Probably either a false positive from the rule checker tool, or the OP is misreading the tools output.

Comment: Headline of question has been changed to 4.14 (not 14.4). Does your answer need adaption?

Comment: @HelpingHand The OP is confused and there's not much making sense of this whole post. Might be better to just close everything as unclear.

Comment: @Lundin - You're right. That would be another reasonable option...